# How to add log messages in tests (spring boot)?

Tags: java, testing, logging, spring-boot

I want to add logging (for console) in my project, for a test in Spring Boot.
I have my test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestConfig.class})
public class MyTest {

    private final static org.slf4j.Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyTest.class);

    @Autowired
    public UserDao userDao;

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        LOGGER.info("info test");
        LOGGER.debug("debug test");
    }
}
```

and my test config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("example.dao")
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = { MyServiceImpl.class})
@EntityScan({"example.model"})
@Import({DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
public class TestConfig {

}
```

I created an `application.properties` file in `test/resource`. Gradle sees my resource folder as a resource for tests.
Here's my `application.properties`:

```
logging.level.= INFO
logging.level.tests.= INFO
logging.level.org.hibernate= INFO
logging.level.org.springframework= INFO
logging.level.org.apache.cxf= INFO
```

But when I run my test, I have:

```
16:59:17.593 [main] INFO  tests.MyTest - info test
16:59:17.594 [main] DEBUG tests.MyTest - debug test
```

in the console. Why?
I set just `'INFO'`(logging.level.= INFO). Why is `'DEBUG'` in the console? How can to set it just to`'INFO'`?

Comment: is it normal the dot character at the end of logging.level and logging.level.tests ?

Answer (score 7):

It's a two step proccess.

First, add `spring-boot-starter-test` as a test dependency. Then tell JUnit to use the `ContextLoader` from the just added dependency.

Change

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestConfig.class})
public class MyTest {
    ...
```

to

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestConfig.class},     
                      loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader.class)
public class MyTest {
    ...
```

The context loader lives in `spring-boot-starter-test` added in the first step and does the initialization magic normally done by the `ApplicationBootstrapper`.

Depending on the spring-boot version you are using there are some other possibilities (e.g. using `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` in place of `@ContextConfiguration`). You can read more about that in this spring blog: https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/15/testing-improvements-in-spring-boot-1-4

Comment: `SpringApplicationContextLoader` was deprecated as of v1.4 in favor of annotating the test class with `@SpringBootTest`, or if absolutely necessary using `SpringBootContextLoader`.   In my case, `@ContextConfiguration` was used to reference the `beans.xml` file, and `@TestPropertySource` was used to reference the `application.properties` file where I had the log level settings.  The new log levels only take effect after the test class starts.  You'll still get the DEBUG logging before that.

Comment: **@EdwinW** I uses `@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)` and it's extremely noisy with default `DEBUG` devel. `SpringBootContextLoader` just do job right (though during bootstrapping it still print several internal DEBUG messages until logging configured from `application.yaml`). Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding @SpringBootConfiguration instead of @ContextConfiguration on your MyTest class.

Follow the example in the Reference doc:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications

> A Spring Boot application is just a Spring ApplicationContext so nothing very special has to be done to test it beyond what you would normally do with a vanilla Spring context. One thing to watch out for though is that the external properties, logging and other features of Spring Boot are only installed in the context by default if you use SpringApplication to create it.